# How to get the style property name using PHP xpath

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I need to get all the tags having style attribute

```
$html = '<div style="font-style: italic; text-align: center; 
background-color: red;">On The Contrary</div><span 
style="font-style: italic; background-color: rgb(244, 249, 255); 
font-size: 32px;"><b style="text-align: center; 
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">This is USA</b></span>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXpath($dom);

foreach ($xp->query('/*[@style]') as $node) {
    $style =  $node->getAttribute('style');
    echo $style;
}
```

but it is ouputing nothing.
What is the error in my code??
Moreover, I also want to get only the CSS PRoperty name in the style, such like font-size, font-weight, font-family and not their values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need one more forward-slash in your expression:

```
foreach( $xp->query('//*[@style]') as $node) {
    echo $node->tagName . " = " . $node->getAttribute('style') . "\n";
}
```

This will print (note that it keeps the line breaks in the existing attributes):

```
div = font-style: italic; text-align: center; 
background-color: red;
span = font-style: italic; background-color: rgb(244, 249, 255); 
font-size: 32px;
b = text-align: center; 
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
```

Answer (score 0):

The xpath selector is

```
//*[@style]
```

For the style content, you will have to parse it, which means

```
$attr_names = array_map( function($v){ return (explode(':',$v))[0];}, 
                          explode(';',$style));
```